# How am I supposed to use the "pdf" package from typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, pdf.js

I have installed pdf including types using

```
npm install --save pdf @types/pdf
```

Unfortantly I cannot find any documentation on how to use this.
If I do:

```
import {PDFJS} from 'pdf';
PDFJS.getDocument(fileName)
```

I get:

```
TyeError: Cannot read 'getDocument' of undefined
```

So how should I initialize this?

Comment: did you also install the pdf package? or only the types package?

Comment: I installed it the way I wrote. That installs the pdf package too, right? I can also find the folder "pdf" in my nodes_modules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:**

Since writing this answer, the type definitions have been renamed to match the NPM package, and a proper export definition has been added, so you can ignore all of the below and just `npm install --save-dev @types/pdf-dist`.

---

**Original Answer:**

This is a consequence of bad package naming - the `@types/pdf` package provides types for Mozilla's PDF.js (which you can obtain via NPM using the [`pdfjs-dist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs-dist) package), *not* the long since abandoned [`pdf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf).

```
npm uninstall --save pdf
npm install --save pdfjs-dist
```

Additionally, it seems like the `@types/pdf` definitions only defines PDF.js as a global variable, not as an importable module. This is despite the fact that the library [definitely supports being imported](https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist/blob/master/build/pdf.js)... Add the following to your project somewhere, it should fix it.

```
declare module "pdfjs-dist" {
    export = { PDFJS };
}
```

Then import PDF.js like so:

```
import { PDFJS } from "pdfjs-dist";
```

Comment: Thank you! I still seem to have problems with the import, because now I get: .../node_modules/@types/pdf/index.d.ts' is not a module.

Comment: @Nathan: Answer updated - as is often the case, the issue lies with flaky type definitions...

Comment: @Nathan: No problem! TypeScript can be a bit of a pain to set up when you're using third party libraries - I tend to have a file in my project called `definitions.d.ts` where I can hide away all the little bits of redefining I have to do.

Comment: All I get when I add those lines is: TS2665: Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'pdfjs-dist' resolves to an untyped module what's going on?

Comment: @ChrisManess: This answer is out of date - the type definitions have since been renamed to match the NPM package, and have a proper export definition. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @JoeClay if you want to take a look at my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467843/importing-pdfjs-breaks-ts-application seems like PDFJS is still broken.

Comment: @ChrisManess Out of curiosity, do any of you actually use those DefinitelyTyped typings? They appear [1] to be written for v0.1.0 from Dec 2011 [2] and overall not in a good shape [3]. (Pull request for inclusion of more recent typings into original project [4] is apparently not about to happen soon.)

[1] https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/pdfjs-dist/index.d.ts
[2] https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist/releases/tag/v0.1.0
[3] https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/7909#issuecomment-357959550
[4] https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/9369