# Importing PDFJS breaks TS application

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf.js

So I'm creating an Angular 2 - typescript application and I want to be able to explore PDFs using Mozilla's PDFJS library. I have installed the depenedencies like so:

```
npm install pdfjs-dist @types/pdfjs-dist --save
```

Then in my app.modules.ts I attempt to import it like so:

```
import { PDFJS } from "pdfjs-dist";
```

And I'm met with the following error when trying to run `tsc` I get the following output:

```
src-ng/csm/app/app.module.ts(27,10): error TS2305: Module '"pdfjs-dist"' has no exported member 'PDFJS'.
```

I'm at a loss because it appears that the pdfjs-dist typing appears to be in order. Is there something else I should include?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to import it like this:

```
import * as PDFJS from "pdfjs-dist";

// or individual members

import { getDocument } from "pdfjs-dist";
```

[This is due to the way TypeScript handles interop between the old module specs (CommonJS, UMD, AMD) and ES6 modules.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242#issuecomment-83694181)